# Debug View Hierarchy fails with exception

Tags: ios, xcode

When I try to debug my view hierarchy on Xcode nothing gets rendered and the console shows this exception (which is ignored).

```
2015-07-16 09:37:56.395 Snapsession[12572:3205485] -[__NSCFType encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1742a5a00
2015-07-16 09:37:56.433 Snapsession[12572:3205485] -[NSCoder(CACoderAdditions) CA_encodeObject:forKey:conditional:]: ignoring exception -[__NSCFType encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1742a5a00
```

The app doesn't really crash at that point cuz I can continue with the execution but the view hierarchy never gets rendered. Any ideas on why this could be happening?

Comment: I would comment out or disable chunks of your app to see if you can pin down what part is causing the issue. You might also want to look in the stack to see where the call to `-encodeWithCoder:` is coming from.